# Proxy settings in Micronaut using HttpClient (Java)

Tags: java, proxy, httpclient, micronaut

So, the problem is, that on one of the wi-fi at work we use proxy and request to external API from my micronaut app gets refused.
Internal Server Error: Connect Error: Connection refused: api.weatherapi.com/138.199...

Doing same request on another wifi without proxy works 100% fine. Also sending same request from plain Java app (with ENV variables set in run config(-Dhttp.proxyHost=aproxy.XXX.net -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080) works fine.

in Micronaut app I am using HttpClient:
import io.micronaut.http.client.HttpClient;
...
URI uri = UriBuilder.of(WEATHER_API_URL)
.path(WEATHER_CURRENT)
.queryParam("key", WEATHER_API_KEY)
.queryParam("q", location)
.queryParam("aqi", "no")
.build();

```
    HttpRequest<?> request = HttpRequest.GET(uri);

    return httpClient.toBlocking().exchange(request, WeatherResponse.class);
}
```

I found that proxy settings can be set in application.yml like this:
micronaut:
http:
client:
proxy-address: aproxy.XXX.net:8080

but then, after sending request I get this ERROR:
Internal Server Error: Connect Error: type DIRECT is not compatible with address aproxy.XXX.net/:8080

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you are missing the protocol (`http://` or  `https://`) prefix for `aproxy.XXX.net:8080`